# Excel: How to allow only one value throughout the column

Tags: vba, excel

I am developing one excel template where 100 or more records will be there.
I have a requirement where, in one of the column, user need to enter the Account ID. Now this account id need to be same for all the 100 records.

Through VBA, i am able to append the Account ID when user is adding one more row (Addition of a row with values in Account ID column using VBA)

I am using data validation which is the inverse of Removal of duplicate values from a column

=COUNTIF($E$4:$E$106,E4)<>1

But these are the problem with this formula

1. When i am changing any value in the parent cell i.e. E4, i am getting error.
2. when i am adding a new row, the value of the formula is getting changed from E4 TO E5.

I need a formula where I should be able to change the value of E4 but not in E5. Also, its should not get incremented when i add a new row.

Also, a VBA code which validates whether a column has one single value in it or not (in complete range saying E4:E104)

Comment: *'I need a formula where I should be able to change the value of E4 but not in E5.'* **contradicts** *'this account id need to be same for all the 100 records'*.

Comment: E4 is the parent cell where user should be able to change the value. But i do not want user to change the value in E5 or any subsequent cells. The formula which i have mentioned above, its not allowing me to change the value in E4. Suppose when i opened excel, it was blank and when i am trying to enter any values to E4, its throwing error. Thats why i told, i should be able to change E4 but not E5

Comment: Is there any other column that is always populated; i.e.never blank?

Comment: No, initially it will be all blank. And only based on user entry in first rows. The second and others rows will have values in E column.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into the worksheet's private code sheet (not a public module code sheet) after removing all data validation from column E.

```
private sub worksheet_change(byval target as range)
    if not intersect(target, range("e:e"), usedrange.offset(3, 0)) is nothing then
        on error goto meh
        application.enableevents = false
        range(cells(4, "e"), cells(rows.count, "e").end(xlup)) = cells(4, "e").value2
    end if

meh:
    application.enableevents = true
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeeped. It worked like charm. Exactly what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

the countif formula that you use for validation will return true if you have more than 1 copy of the correct ID. It doesn't return false if you have different Id's as long as you have atleast 2 of what is in E4, when you change it to a different thing it turns to false and you get your error.

You should use and(exact($E$4:$E$104,E$4)) for your validation

Comment: =AND(EXACT($E$4:$E$104,E$4)) with this formula also, i am not able to change the value in E4 even though there is no rows other than E4.

Comment: I am sorry with that formula it will take the blank values in the rest of the range as different values. 
If the ID is just a number you can do if(max($E$4:$E$104)=min($E$4:$E$104)) it wont work for text fields though

Comment: Actually, its a account id field so text is required. Thanks a lot for your response.